# Google Analytics UA Measurement Protocol events not working across multiple properties as of June 17 2021

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics, measurement-protocol

We have several Universal Analytics properties (not GA4) which have been set up over the last few years.

Some older properties were set up as 'Mobile' which is no longer an option, the newer properties were set up as 'Web'.

These are node.js apps where we are tracking custom events server side. We do not send page views for any of these properties, only custom events using the 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect' measurement protocol endpoint.

This has always worked fine but as of June 16/17 2021, all our 'Web' properties are showing no data in the Behaviour / Audience reports. I can still see the events appearing in the 'Realtime' section, so I know they are still being received by GA.

Here you can see the data for one of the properties feeding through to the realtime dashboard. This data now no longer syncs to the Behaviour/Audience section etc.

[image: realtime events displaying as usual]

Here is the total events for the same app. Displays nothing after June 16/17.

[image: example of empty report 1]

Here is another property which has stable traffic. Exact same thing. This has happened to many properties, all on the same day.

[image: example of empty report 2]

Does anyone have any ideas what is wrong here? Feels like Google have changed something but not informed us. I have already 'sent feedback' on GA and posted on the GA community forum with no replies as of yet.

Comment: As far as i know they havent changed anything.   But i sent off an email to the team to double check as this looks a little strange to me.

Comment: I heard back from the team they are looking into it.

Comment: That's great, thank you. Please let me know if you hear anything more.

Comment: I can confirm the exact same issue on multiple analytics accounts (not GA4). Code was not changed but measurement protocol events stopped showing since June 17. The events are still shown in the real time reports so for sure they are sent correctly.

Comment: Submit a support request using the form at the following page and include the property ID(s) of the affected properties. You can basically just copy/paste what you have here but include the property ID info with the request: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/help#contact-us

Comment: Thanks, tried that but they told me it's a UI issue, not an API issue so I should buy a Google Ads product to unlock support.

Comment: I found your support request submission. We're looking into the issue.

Comment: Hi @Pete, do you know if the team has been able to look at this issue yet? Wondering if it's something you think will be fixed / when that might be. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's still under review. The info from the answer below has been added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was experiencing the same issue with my GA properties. I reached out to GA support & they recommended creating a new view without the spider / bot exclusion filter and now these events are reporting as expected. They also recommended adding user agent strings to existing MP.

Comment: Thank you. Since changing this setting, the events and traffic are now being reported again. Just to make people aware, the traffic for the period between June 17 and updating this setting will still show as empty. I'm not sure if there is a way to get this data back in the reports. This also feels like a workaround rather than a fix for the root issue so hoping Google will address the cause of this at some point soon.